# Scopes Not Present in JWT Claim in Golang and Goa

Tags: go, jwt, auth0

I am using the excellent `goa` package to generate my API in Go.

However, I am having an issue with its security middleware and when I submit a bearer token to my controllers, I get "authorization failed" because of "scopes:null". I am using Auth0 for authentication and it is generating the bearer token. The exact error in Postman is:

```
{"id":"xOUR882s","code":"jwt_security_error","status":401,"detail":"authorization failed: required 'scopes' not present in JWT claim","meta":{"required":["read:meta"],"scopes":null}}
```

However, my token does include the required scope `read:meta`. [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) gives back the following decoded bearer:

```
{
  "iss": "https://learnlogic.au.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "exJMkK7hXX56lrLwoTqna3s0jh7Gq67e@clients",
  "aud": "https://api.learn-logic.com",
  "exp": 1494855336,
  "iat": 1494768936,
  "scopes": "read:meta"
}
```

I am hoping someone can help me workout why, as I don't really understand what is going on in `middleware/jwt.go` in the `goa` project which may be found [here](https://github.com/goadesign/goa/blob/master/middleware/security/jwt/jwt.go). My only thought is that something about the Auth0 formatted bearer is not compatible with the `parseClaimScopes` function in `middleware/jwt.go`, but I don't know what.

I have the following `main.go` code:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("util/jwt.key")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(b))
    var cert *x509.Certificate
    cert, _ = x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    rsaPublicKey := cert.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    fmt.Println(rsaPublicKey.N)
    fmt.Println(rsaPublicKey.E)
    fmt.Println(cert)

    var keyx = []jwt.Key{rsaPublicKey}

    var jwtResolver = jwt.NewSimpleResolver(keyx)

    app.UseJWTMiddleware(service, jwt.New(jwtResolver, nil, app.NewJWTSecurity()))
```

The certificate I am reading in is the same one used in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) to decode the bearer token.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was wondering if that was a problem but I didn't know what to say about it. I thought that what `scopes` got called in a `jwt` was standardised? In any case, how would I change either a) the Auth0 token or, b) the `goa` implementation to allow for `scopes` instead of `scope`?

Comment: Hmm.  The scope claim is something relatively new (deleted my earlier comment) and realize I'm not sure what I'm talking about here.  Sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

According to this ticket https://github.com/goadesign/goa/issues/1228, the problem was due to the fact there was only a support for a claim with a singular name "scope" and not the plural "scopes". This PR https://github.com/goadesign/goa/pull/1399, added the plural version.